# Destination Host unreachable from inside Docker Container to remote SQL Server Database behind VPN

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn

I'm trying to "dockerize" a net application.

My database is in the company servers and we connect to them through VPN with double factor authentication. I can do this correctly with no problem.

My app runs correctly without Docker and I can access it with my app and other tools like SSMS.

The problem comes when I try to run the app from a docker container. Here is my docker compose:

```
services:
  orenes.procedimientos.firma.api:
    environment:
      - TZ=CET
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:6555
      - ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__FirmasConnString=Server=10.1.33.34;Database=YYYY;User ID=ZZZZ;password=******
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}orenesprocedimientosfirmaapi
    extra_hosts:
      - "SV-GORDEVSQL:10.1.33.34"
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: Orenes.Procedimientos.Firma.API/Dockerfile
      network: host
    ports:
      - 6555:6555

    networks:
      - vpn

networks:
    vpn:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 10.1.0.0/20
```

If I go inside the container and try to do a ping towards the server URL, I receive

`From 10.1.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable`

This is the output of the ifconfig command:

```
th0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.1.0.255
        ether 02:42:0a:01:00:02  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 330  bytes 394185 (384.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 278  bytes 16675 (16.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15  bytes 1300 (1.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 1300 (1.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Running Docker Desktop on Windows 10.

If someone can help, I will be really grateful.

Thx!